# Starting a process with a key stroke in linux

Tags: linux, process, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to ask something that just came to my mind. I search google and stackoverflow and couldn't find a answer to my question, if there is any, please inform me.

Is it possible to bind a process to a combination of key strokes? For example, can i start my program with simply pushing the buttons <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> or it can be any other function keys. Is it possible to start a process like that? I know that i must compile kernel and boot up again if it is possible but i couldn't find the place where the meaning of key combinations stored.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with programming or development. Why would you ask it here? Stack Overflow is not a twitter dump for random thoughts.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I hate the way of organizing topic in "stack" general site. There is no info given about "it must be purely about programming or development". This is more about computstionsl field and i found nothing to warn me about "not posting program/environment specific questions". And the way people learn where they should ask these kind of questions comes after punishment of downvote. I am sorry about it. Next time i will look for other stack sites.

Comment: Take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) or check the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Its pretty clear about what's on-topic for Stack Overflow. The first paragraph of the tour explains: *"... we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming."* With that said, Stack Overflow does a poor job of educating folks. Its why I leave the custom message that tries to explain things, and tell you where the question might be on-topic.

Comment: @OzanPolatbilek It's certainly hard to keep track of [all the different Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list)! And there are new ones sprouting up all the time. Let's all be patient with Stack Overflow questions that belong on a different [technology-related site](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid#technology).

Comment: @OzanPolatbilek - Now open on Meta: [Please provide a tagline with site purpose by logo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358111/608639).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `bind` for this, i.e. to run `pwd` when F12 is pressed

```
 bind '"\e[24~":"pwd\n"'
```

move program you want to run to `/usr/bin` or another directory in the stadard path use the path in the `bind` command

```
 bind '"\e[24~":"absolute_path_to_program/program"'
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89622/how-to-execute-a-script-in-shell-when-a-shortcut-key-is-pressed